# JQuery Ajax and Object field

Tags: jquery, ajax, object

I have this code:

```
MyObject = function(){
    this.field = null;

    this.build = function(){
        var my_url = "...";
        var my_data = "...";
        $.get(my_url, my_data, function(result){
           this.field = result;
        });
    }

    this.get = function(){
        return this.field;
    }
}

object = new MyObject();
object.build();
my_result = object.get()
```

`my_result` now is `null` because when the inner function is executed `this` is not my object.
So, how can i set `this.field` with the `$.get` returned value???

Comment: _please_ don't call your object `Object`!

Comment: @Alnitak ok i'll call MyObject...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the top of your constructor, do:

```
var self = this;
```

this creates a new scoped variable that refers to the current object.

Then in the AJAX call back do:

```
self.field = result;
```

Comment: I recommmend doing this inside the method `this.build` so that `object.build.apply(scope, ...)` doesn't break.

Comment: in practise if it mattered I'd probably do both.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyObject = function(){
    this.field = null;

    this.build = function(cb){
        var my_url = "...";
        var my_data = "...";
        var self = this;
        $.get(my_url, my_data, function(result){
           self.field = result;
           cb(result);
        });
    }

    this.get = function(){
        return this.field;
    }
}

object = new MyObject();
object.build(function(field) {
    console.log(object.get() === field);
});
```

I recommend you pass a callback to your build function so you can be notified *immediatly* when your field is set.

Also placing `var self = this` inside your method ensures that you can call `object.build.call(scope, f)` without it being bound to the wrong scope.

This pattern is particularly useful in inheritance when you want to call a method of another class.

Comment: pls elaborate on the scope issue - are you saying that you might specifically want to use a different scope than that of the constructed object itself?

Comment: @Alnitak you might want to reuse it. its an OOP pattern.

Answer (score 1):

In the future, try using the Module Pattern:

**HERE IS THE MODULE PATTERN:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myNamespace = (function($) {
        var publicInstances = {};

        // ***********************
        // myObject
        publicInstances.myObject = myObject;
        function myObject() {

            /// <summary>A pointer to this</summary>
            var self = this;

            this.someProperty = new String();

            this.initialize = function() {
                /// your code here
            }
            this.someMethod = function() {
                /// your code here
            }

            self.initialize();
        }

        return publicInstances;
    })(jQuery);


    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        // Use would look like
        var myInstance = new myNamespace.myObject();
    });
</script>
```

**HERE IS WHAT YOUR OBJECT MIGHT LOOK LIKE:**

> ```
> var myNamespace = (function($) 
> {
>     var publicInstances = {};
>
>     // ***********************
>     // myObject
>     publicInstances.myObject = myObject;
>     function myObject(url, data) {
>
>         /// <summary>A pointer to this</summary>
>         var self = this;
>         /// <summary>Contains the result</summary>
>         this.field = null; // Name this result instead.
>
>         this.url = url;
>         this.data = data;
>
>         this.initialize = function() {
>             /// Initialize whatever
>         }
>         this.build = function() {
>             $.get(self.url, self.data, function(result) {
>                 self.field = result;
>                 cb(self.field);
>             });
>         }
>         this.cb = function(result) {
>             /// Do whatever
>         }
>
>         self.initialize();
>     }
>
>     return publicInstances;
> })(jQuery);
> ```

Comment: that pattern is a bit over engineered and not that good. Still leaking into global scope. and your not opening yourself to async loaders. But it is better then just adhoc coding !

Comment: I don't see what you mean by "leaking" into global scope. If you mean you would create a persistent object...I don't see that as bad. In fact, that is exactly what he wants to do.  How's this? If you don't like it please post an better alternative?

Comment: Additionally, the Module Pattern is widely used...and I got it from a John Resig example!

Comment: @Raynos - There is a discussion of your comment going on at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951228/what-is-meant-by-leaking-into-global-scope. If you would like to participate?