# What does the define() protocol outlined in CommonJS specification buy me?

Tags: javascript, curl, requirejs

I understand how things like **[proper name-spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/javascript-namespace-declaration)** and the **[Module Pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth)** help issues associated with **[leaking into the global-scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951228/what-is-meant-by-leaking-into-global-scope)**.

I also completely see the value of resource dependency-management provided for in the `require()` protocol outlined in the **[CommonJS Specification](http://www.commonjs.org/)**.

However, I am befuddled as to the benefit of the AMD `define()` function's use and purpose.

**The CommonJS signature for define is:**

```
define(id?, dependencies?, factory);
```

**Additionally…**

- I see people [**wrapping their Module
  Pattern plug-ins with `define()`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869530/requirejs-how-to-define-modules-that-contain-a-single-class) when
  BOTH create an object at the
  global-scope.
- A file containing a normal Module
  Pattern plug-in can be loaded
  asynchronously as well.

At first, it "seemed" like yet-another plug-in wrapper...until I began to see folks use it alongside the Module Pattern.

**So My Questions Are:**

- What does the `define()` protocol
  outlined in CommonJS specification
  buy me?
- Is it somehow more eloquent?
- Is it meant to replace the Modular Pattern?
- Is it somehow faster?
- If so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// main.js
require("foo.js", function(foo) {
    console.log(foo === 42); // true
});

//foo.js

/*
define(42);

define({
   "foo": "bar"
});

define(["bar.js"], function(bar) {
    return bar.foo;
});
*/

define(function() {
     return 42;
});
```

Define is a great way to pass modular objects back without relying on global scope.

The particular API of define varies from library to library though.

Here the basic idea is that you call define in a file to define what that module is. Then when you require the file you get the module. This cuts out the middle man that is global scope.

It's no faster though (It's slower then injecting into global scope).

Using `require` and `define` you only have two global values.

The particular `define` example above matches the [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/) API

Comment: So...every object is appended into the global-define object for you?

Comment: @PrisonerZERO not appended. Your simply calling `define`. Define will then pass it back through your `require` callback. These objects are not stored anywhere, it's just message passing. They are cached somewhere internally though. But not publically available.

Comment: Since it isn't stored anywhere...I'm guessing you should use this pattern ONLY when it isn't a persistent object & you want to run once.

Comment: @PrizonerZERO all objects should not be stored anywhere. Have to objects bind to Pubsub systems, eventemitters, events on the DOM, etc. You don't need global state, you just need an object to react to state changes through event based messages rather then direct messages through a global object.