# How to get multiple elements in array by class?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, get, element

I am trying to get multiple elements using an array. I'm bad at describing, so I'll try and show.

```
var modal = document.querySelectorAll(".myModal")[0]; // <-- gets the first element in an array
var modal = document.querySelectorAll(".myModal")[1]; // <-- gets the second element in an array; doesn't work
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: We need more context here to be able to answer the question. 
Please provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
var modal = document.querySelectorAll(".myModal");  //one time
modal[0] //first element
modal[1] //second element
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var parent = document.querySelectorAll('.myModal');
Array.prototype.slice.call(parent).forEach(function(child){ 

// your code 

});
```

Hope you are looking for this as your question doesn't give any idea what you want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can this is several ways, you can read more about how to iterate through it at [Accessing the matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#accessing_the_matches)

Note that you cannot have the same variable twice, in your code rename the second one and it will work: [Declaring two variable with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23710231/declaring-two-variable-with-the-same-name/23806496)

```js
// one way
let modal0 = document.querySelectorAll(".myModal")[0];
let modal1 = document.querySelectorAll(".myModal")[1];

console.log("one way")
console.log(modal0)
console.log(modal1)

//another way
const modalElemenet = document.querySelectorAll(".myModal");
let firstElement = modalElemenet[0];
let secondElement = modalElemenet[1];

console.log("second way")
console.log(firstElement);
console.log(secondElement);

// take all childrens
const modal = document.querySelectorAll(".myModal");
console.log("take all")
modal.forEach(e => console.log(e));
```

```html
<div class="myModal"> 1 </div>
<div class="myModal"> 2 </div>
<div class="myModal"> 3 </div>
```