# variables from IIFE accessible in global scope

Tags: javascript, iife

how come the output of this IIFE is 5?

```
(function() {
  var a = b = 5;
})();

console.log(b);
```

I tried console.log(a) but it gives a reference error as expected
how come 'b' is alive in global scope?

Comment: Try separate assignments and variable declarations. This shouldn't work in strict mode.

Comment: I wanna understand why does it work?

Comment: i might be completely wrong, but is this related to hoisting somehow?

Comment: It has nothing to do with hoisting

Comment: you are not in strict mode, b is not declared in scope, so it get created on the global object(global or window). in strict mode, you will get an error when assigning to b. this is a good question and i am sure it is dublicated. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question. Though it is not related to IIFE's or hoisting at all. Notice how "a" is not defined!

Your code sample

```
function test() {
  var a = b = 5;
}
```

is semantically equivalent to this:

```
function test() {
  var a = 5;
  // this is essentially the same as `window.b = a`
  b = a;
}
```

since you did not declare "a" (aka `var a;`) it ends up in the global scope.
In strict mode this would not work.

Answer (score 4):

This is happening simply because you're declaring `b` as a global variable, not a local one.

```
(function() {
  var a = b = 5;
})();
```

It may *look* like it's being defined locally because of `var`, but that applies to `a` only.

Answer (score 2):

That's because of "leaking", which means to unintentionally make locally declared variables available to the global scope. More informations about can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951228/what-is-meant-by-leaking-into-global-scope). Let's split your code:

```
var a = b = 5;
```

This means: `a` takes the value of `b`, which is 5. The variable `b` is implicitly declared and initialised in this case (with `b = 5`), and since you're not specifying its block scope (that's because `var` is referring to `a`, not `b`) it's bounded to the global scope.

Answer (score 2):

that`s behavior is related to scope in non "strict mode",

when function is trying to execute, it find a function scope variable called a,
and you don`t have access to it from outer scope and it will facing and error.

for the b variable it couldn't find declaration and go one level up and asked global scope about variable b and scope manager can`t find any var b, it will create it right away in global scope for you, result is you can log it in global scope, this thing calls (dynamic variable).

Answer (score 0):

[To declare multiple variables,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/694102/3552975) you need to do this way:

```
(function() {
  var a = 5, b = 5;
})();

console.log(b);
```

An expected error will occur:

```
VM376:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: b is not defined
    at <anonymous>:5:13
```